# restore a deleted imported metamask account

Tags: metamask, wallets, accounts, import, recovery

i had my metamask wallet stoled, and my first reaction was delete the stole account. But this account has some pools os pancakeswap, and i need to restore it to save my tokens. I have the seed phrase and recovered the wallet, than created new accounts but the deleted account don't appears. important informetion s that this account is a imported account. is there any way to recover it? pleas help me

Answer (score 0):

If your wallet was stolen, deleting it will not do anything-as it just removes it from the Metamask UI, not from the blockchain. You most likely imported that account with your private key. Metamask does NOT store or associate private key imported accounts with your seed phrase. If you are missing the private key to that account, then it's unfortunately... gone.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Create a new account inside your main account, (don't put any name) and hit create button.
Doing this will load your sub accounts created before one by one and in order.
For example if your information was on 4th account then by creating 3 account Metamask will load your willing account.

(2) but Metamask won't load any imported-one from a different main account(wallet). For loading imported account you need privet keys for imported account or the main account's seeds and following same steps (1) until you load your account.

(3) Otherwise I think we cant load or recover our wallet.

(4) if anyone can recover an imported account in different ways please let me know because I have same problem.